# Where can I get Melfor vinegar in Spain? Or can someone suggest a good substitute?

Tags: vinegar, french-cuisine

It's a low-acid vinegar from the Alsace region of France, made with spirit (alcohol) vinegar and honey, and infused with herbs. There is a version of it available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CMU33U0).

I can't find anywhere to buy it here in Spain. Does anyone know where I may be able to purchase it or order it online for delivery to Spain? Alternatively, can somebody recommend a substitution?

Comment: Did you try contacting them directly to see if they have distributors in Spain ? Maybe big box like El Corte Ingles have them ?

Comment: Thanks @Cindy and Jefromi for helping me understand the norms here. I'll edit my question to ask for substitutions instead of recipes. And thanks Max, I'll try that if I get desperate.